# How to send json array in Dialogflow V2

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on Dialogflow chatbot, I am using Webhook to get response from server for some queries. For simple text i can read from fulfillment but if i want to receive array how can i put json array in v1 webhook fulfillment.

```
 code:
    var json = {
    "fulfillmentText":"something"
    "fulfillmentMessages":[
      {
        "name":"Something"
      }  
      ] 
    }
      const speech = res.result.fulfillment.speech;
```

Comment: Can you update your question to illustrate what you mean by "receive array", possibly showing code about how you're sending the request and what you expect back in the reply?

Comment: i just need to send some array data other than string

Comment: in fulfillmenttext we can send only string, i want send some json object data

Comment: How are you sending the request? How do you plan to use the JSON results?